# I have problems storing Date from JDateChooser into MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jdatechooser

I am having problems passing data from my GUI to MySQL database.  I am collecting information from `JTextField`s and `JDateChooser`, into the database.  Everything else works, except the date.  I tried multiple methods that I found online, and none of them have worked. I also checked the table, to ensure that the "DATE" data type is enabled in my "patientinfo" Table.  If I remove the JDateChooser, my query works. Otherwise, I will get this error message:

**Java.lang.NullPointerException**

I am including my source code with this message.

```
//Event handler adds records
//to the database

JButton subInfoBtn = new JButton("SUBMIT AND CONTINUE");

subInfoBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            try {
                //Invokes "javaconnect" class
                //to link to MySQL database
                conn = javaconnect.ConnecrDb();

                //Invokes SQL Statement from "Connection" Object
                pst = conn.createStatement();

                //SQL query commands event handler to access
                //"patientinfo" table, to insert data to columns.
                pst.executeUpdate("INSERT into patientinfo(firstName, lastName, DOB, age, SSN, "
                                  + "address, phone,email, emergencycontact, emergencyphone) "
                                  + "VALUES" + "('"+firstTxt.getText() + "', '" + lastTxt.getText()
                                  + "', '" + DOBTxt.getDate() + "' ,'" + ageTxt.getText() + "', '"
                                  + ssnTxt.getText() + "', "+ " '" + addressTxt.getText() +"',
                                  '"+phoneTxt.getText()+"'  , '"+emailTxt.getText()+"'  ,
                                  '"+emergencyTxt.getText()+"'  , '"+emergPhoneTxt.getText()+"'  )");


                //Closes Database Connection
                conn.close();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pantient Information Saved Succesfully");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
        }
    });

    subInfoBtn.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    subInfoBtn.setBounds(305, 286, 220, 23);
    contentPane.add(subInfoBtn);

//Also, I have tried to use SimpleDateFormat and
//((JTextField)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
//Without any luck.  I am also aware of using Prepare Statement to avoid SQL injections, but
//I would like to solve the JDateChooser bonding data dilema into MySQL database.
```

Comment: When posting a question, please reduce your code the smallest possible example that shows your problem/question, preferably a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this
Convert the java.util.Date you are taking input to java.sql.Date for storing it to Mysql database as mysql stores Date in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`

```
public static java.sql.Date convertUtilDateToSqlDate(java.util.Date date){
    if(date != null) {
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
        return sqlDate;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then do it his way

```
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO patientinfo"+
                                     "(firstName, lastName, DOB, age, SSN, address," +
                                     "phone,email, emergencycontact, emergencyphone)"+
                                     "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
statement.setTimestamp(1,sqlDate);
statement.setString(1,firstTxt.getText());
statement.setString(2,lastTxt.getText());
statement.setDate(3,convertUtilDateToSqlDate(DOBTxt.getDate()));
statement.setString(4,ageTxt.getText());
statement.setString(5,ssnTxt.getText());
statement.setString(6,addressTxt.getText());
statement.setString(7,phoneTxt.getText());
statement.setString(8,emailTxt.getText());
statement.setString(9,emergencyTxt.getText());
statement.setString(10,emergPhoneTxt.getText());
int i = statement.executeUpdate();
if(i>0){
    System.out.println("Successfull");
 }
```

I hope you will do the necessary Exception handling and connection closing

Comment: SparkOn, thank you for taking the time to help me with my jdatechooser dilemma.   I tried to implement the h ava.sql.Date class and I still get the sameJava.lang.NullPointerException error.   Do you have any other ideas of to solve this issue?   I also made sure that my table has the "DATE" data type, and the columns order matches the same sequence as my source code, and nothing.

Comment: In addition,  I tried to implement PreparedStatement,  and it does not work for me.   I have another column in my table called "patientID", which generates an auto integer.  Since I'm not declaring the "patientID" column in my query,  dies it matter which index I declare on my query?  For example, patientID is column 1 on the patientinfo table,  but I just want the user to enter the rest of the data.  Therefore,  using thestatement.setString(1,firstTxt.getText()); would still be valid?   Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Hi again SparkOn. I managed to implement the PrepareStatement, but I am still having trouble to enter the date using the JDateChooser from the JCalendar library.  I even tried the java.sql.Date class conversion that you mentioned before, and nothing.  Thanks for your help again.

Comment: having trouble like what?

Comment: I am still getting the same Java.lang.NullPointerException when I try to use the JDateChooser.  If I remove the JDateChooser and the DOB column from my query, everything else works.

Comment: that may be because your date is coming as null

Answer (score 1):

```
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(dateChooser.getDate().getTime());
```

Convert `Date` to sql object then store in database. Hope it will work.

Comment: Hi Ishwar, Thank you for your help.  I already used the java.sql.Date class, and I'm still getting theJava.lang.NullPointerException.  I don't know what else to do.   I also tried different other methods and classes,  and still, no joy.  The same message.   I have also passed parameters and if... else statements to the classes, in case the JDateChooser component is empty, and I still get the same outcome.   Do you have any other ideas?   Thank you again for helping me.